# In Odoo is there a way to control the form view showed when a row is clicked in a tree view

Tags: odoo

When a row is clicked in a tree view, I want to change the model to a child model based on the value of a field. Where do I need to go to override the click action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a row is clicked in Odoo the fuction reponsible to open selected record is ***_onRowClicked*** in */home/amal/0Work/Odoo/SourceCode/odoo-12.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js*.

In Odoo you can hide and display fields according to the current user/ fields available in the model. So before overriding default functions in Odoo make sure you don't have any other alternatives.